# What is the purpose of TaskCreationOptions with a TaskCompletionSource?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, taskcompletionsource

There's something unclear to me about the inner workings of `TaskCompletionSource<>`.

When creating a simple `Task<>` using the `Factory`, I expect this task to be enqueued in a thread pool, unless I specify `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`, where it will run in a new thread instead.

My understanding of `TaskCompletionSource`, is that I am responsible of triggering when a task ends, or fails, and I have full control on how to manage threads.
However, the ctor of `TaskCompletionSource` allows me to specify a `TaskCreationOptions`, and this confuse me, since I was expecting the `Scheduler` not being able to handle the task itself.

What is the purpose of `TaskCreationOptions` in the context of a `TaskCompletionSource<>`?

Here is an example of use:

```
public Task<WebResponse> Download(string url)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<WebResponse> tcs = 
    new TaskCompletionSource<WebResponse>(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    var client = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    var async = client.BeginGetResponse(o =>
      {
          try
          {
              WebResponse resp = client.EndGetResponse(o);
              tcs.SetResult(resp);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              tcs.SetException(ex);
          }
      }, null);


    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Well, you can see what was used through the resulting task, so I suppose it's possible that some code could be passed a TCS or a Task and do something based on the result of one of those options (in the custom code that is processing this task).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that a TaskCreationOption is useful for its AttachToParent option only, as TaskCompletionSource can be the child of any other task.
Options related to thread management or execution ordering aren't relevant in the context of a TaskCompletionSource. The following code actually throws an exception:

```
new TaskCompletionSource<WebResponse>(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Comment: Suppose I call your method with `await Download("http://example.com")`, does attachment matter? I would guess that I am implicitly attached based on the fact that I'm awaiting the result... or is there more to it?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, as you probably know `await Download("http://example.com")` is just syntaxic sugar for `Download("http://example.com").ContinueWith( task => { /* then */}`. So parent/child attachment is a relevant possibility, but this is probably bad practice.

Comment: Ah not so. TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously is really useful on TaskCompletionSource.